# при выполнении задания на степике в песочнице пишут такую ошибку : Parse error: unrecognized token: "$"

Tags: sqlite3

```
$ sqlite3 city-1.db
SQLite version 3.38.0 2022-02-22 18:58:40
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> .import --csv city.csv city
sqlite> select count(*) from city;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: что мне нужно исправить в песочнице, чтобы не выдавало такую ошибку : Parse error: unrecognized token: "$"

Comment: Отредактируйте сообщение, чтобы стало видно весь текст. Просто добавьте переводы строк.

Comment: Неужели так сложно просто взять и отредактировать своё сообщение? На это нужно несколько секунд. После чего становится видно символ `$`. Полагаю, вы просто копипастите показанный текст?